# Use Service Account with GoogleAdsClient to make AdWordsSession

Tags: java, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-java-client

I want to use Google Ads API with service account I managed to create a session using this Java code configuration:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        File configFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("ads.properties").getFile());

        GoogleAdsClient googleAdsClient = GoogleAdsClient.newBuilder()
                .fromEnvironment()
                .fromPropertiesFile(configFile)
                .build();

        GoogleAdsServiceClient googleAdsServiceClient = googleAdsClient.getLatestVersion().createGoogleAdsServiceClient();
```

I want to use this connection to make a request using this code:

```
AdWordsSession session = null;
        try {
            // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential.
            Credential oAuth2Credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
                            .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
                            .fromFile()
                            .build()
                            .generateCredential();

            // Construct an AdWordsSession.
            session =
                    new AdWordsSession.Builder().fromFile().build();
        } catch (ConfigurationLoadException cle) {
            System.err.printf(
                    "Failed to load configuration from the %s file. Exception: %s%n",
                    DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILENAME, cle);
            return;
        } catch (ValidationException ve) {
            System.err.printf(
                    "Invalid configuration in the %s file. Exception: %s%n",
                    DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILENAME, ve);
            return;
        } catch (OAuthException oe) {
            System.err.printf(
                    "Failed to create OAuth credentials. Check OAuth settings in the %s file. "
                            + "Exception: %s%n",
                    DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILENAME, oe);
            return;
        }

        AdWordsServicesInterface adWordsServices = AdWordsServices.getInstance();

        try {
            runExample(adWordsServices, session);
        } catch (ApiException apiException) {
            System.err.println("Request failed due to ApiException. Underlying ApiErrors:");
            if (apiException.getErrors() != null) {
                int i = 0;
                for (ApiError apiError : apiException.getErrors()) {
                    System.err.printf("  Error %d: %s%n", i++, apiError);
                }
            }
        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            System.err.printf(
                    "Request failed unexpectedly due to RemoteException: %s%n", re);
        }
```

> AdWordsServicesInterface adWordsServices, AdWordsSession session) throws RemoteException {
> // Get the TrafficEstimatorService.
> TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface trafficEstimatorService =
> adWordsServices.get(session, TrafficEstimatorServiceInterface.class);

Full source: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/java/basic-operations

Do you know how I can use service account into the above code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Adwords does support service account Authentication

[OAuth2 service accounts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#oauth2_service_accounts)

> The AdWords API allows service account access through G Suite domains.

Which means you need to have your Gsuite domain admin authorize your service account to access it.

The Code should look something like this to authorize a service account

```
 /**
   * Initializes an adwords service object.
   *
   * @return An authorized adwords  service object.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException
   */
  private static AdWordsServices initializeAdWords() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .createScoped(AdwordsScopes.all());

    // Construct the Analytics Reporting service object.
    return new AdWordsServices.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you show me how I can use this code with my example code?

Comment: Your code is intended for Oauth2 not service account, i am suggesting you use this instead of your code.

Comment: Could you please extend the example a little bit more? How I have to replace the Session object?

Comment: Why do you need the session object. I showed you how to create the adWordsServices all your requests go though that.

Comment: ok, can you extend your example a little more, please?